# IIS 7.5 Configure default location for FTP user account Not specifically named according to user account

Tags: ftp, iis-7.5

I am moving an FTP server from 2003 to 2008R2 and am having an issue setting up a like configuration.

Issue currently is I have a folder structure for example wherein the default root of the FTP is `D:\FTP`

```
D:\FTP\State1\County1
D:\FTP\State1\County2
D:\FTP\State1\County3
D:\FTP\State2\County2
```

Then a user account of `User1` that I want to start in `D:\State1\County2`

In the 2003 server we simply set under the local user account properties on the `Profile` tab the Home Folder = `D:\State1\County2` and upon login that is the default directory the user sees content in.

The 2008 server when I try to login with the same structure and account properties it simply dumps me to the root of the FTP structure and I have to CD into the folder necessary, which also allows immediate visibility of other directories even though access is denied upon attempting to open.

All the user isolation modes I have seen require the folder for the arriving location to be named according the user account and this wont work for me.

Any suggestions appreciated.

Comment: Did you read this article for the options you have available with your type of server setup http://www.iis.net/learn/publish/using-the-ftp-service/configuring-ftp-user-isolation-in-iis-7? You may be stuck with this and have to come up with a strategy. I'd create one test account on the new server and play with the options to see if I could make something work. The FTP server via the IIS on Windows doesn't seem very robust so I actually use a better server solution which supports FTPS (implicit and explicit), SFTP, insecure FTP, HTTPS, is FIPS compliant, and cost effective... Wing FTP Server.

Comment: I had not come across that article yet, but I think this comment from that page defines the issue I am experiencing. `Note: This option is new in this FTP server, and simply disables all user isolation or starting folder logic.`